# Numbered lists in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create a numbered list (with sub-lists) in a WPF based UI. I'm aware of `BulletDecorator` for creating bullet lists and I was hoping there might be something similar for numbered lists.

I'm hoping to achieve something like:

> 1. List item
> 2. List item
>
>    a) Sub list item
>
>    b) Sub list item
> 3. List item

Ideally I'd also like to have some control over the numbering format to enable use of lettering (such as shown for the sub-items).

Comment: `BulletDecorator` isn't just for creating bullet lists. You can use it for showing other things in the position of bullet.

Comment: like svick says, you can set the Bullet in a BulletDecorator to any UIElement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.bulletdecorator.bullet.aspx

Comment: So how might you envisage re-templating a bullet decorator for the purposes of numbering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FlowDocument with List. The FlowDocument/List example on the bottom of this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list.aspx) shows an example similar to what you want to create.

Comment: Yes! That's the look I want. I didn't mention this as a requirement but I believe I cannot use input controls (textbox/radio/etc) within a FlowDocument right?

Comment: @Reddog (Even though the question is quite old, this is for future visitors) Yes, you can. You must place them inside a `Paragraph` or `BlockUIContainer` though.