# Write text with bullets and numbering WPF

Tags: wpf, text-formatting

I need to insert into a border text with bullets (look at the next picture for example):

[image: example]

Is there any special property for this or should I use some container like grid and get this manually?
If your solution rely on Expression Blend it fine by me (I`m using Blend 4).

Thanks
Ofir

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290159/numbered-lists-in-wpf)?

Comment: I tried to find similar question and I didn`t see this thread.
Thank you.